# Acceder a un dato especifico dentro de un objeto JSON

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, mongoose

Mi situación es la siguiente, tengo datos dentro de un objeto json, y que quiero acceder a los id de idSocket que están dentro de un array de un usuario especifico, y a la vez, los usuarios se encuentran dentro de usersOnline. Utilizo express y mongoose para acceder a los datos, he buscado varias maneras de hacerlo, pero ninguno me ha dado resultado. Disculpen si mi redacción no es bueno, soy nuevo en esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462318/find-a-value-in-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript) tienes un ejemplo bastante sencillo de lo que buscas. Simplemente recorres tu lista de usuarios `json.usersOnline` (tomando `json` como la variable que contiene todos tus datos) y vas buscando coincidencias para el usuario que esperas (con un `if`).

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que preguntas, no acaba de quedar claro la finalidad o el método a usar para acceder a los datos. Aún así, pongo un ejemplo de cómo lo podrías hacer, según suposiciones:

#### Buscar ID de socket de un usuario

```javascript
const findSocket = (json, idUser, idSocket) => {
  const user = json.usersOnline
    .find( u => u._id === idUser);
  return user?.idSocket.find( socket => socket === idSocket) /* undefined if not found */
}
```

#### Buscar un Usuario por ID de socket

```javascript
const findUserBySocket = (json, idSocket) => {
  return json.usersOnline
    .find( u => u.idSocket.includes(idSocket) );
}
```

#### Listar los ID de socket de un usuario

```javascript
const findSocketsByUser = (json, idUser) => {
  const user = json.usersOnline
    .find( u => u._id === idUser );
  return user?.idSocket
}
```